# Calculate s = 1 / sin1 + 1 / (sin1 + sin2) + ... 1 / sin (1 + .. n)

Tags: python

using while and for  Calculate s = 1 / sin1 + 1 / (sin1 + sin2) + ... 1 / sin (1 + .. n).

```
import math
 = int(input("Enter n: ")`
s=0
i=1
for i in range(n):
     s+=1/math.sin(n)
     i=i+1
     print(s)
```

Comment: I am only beginner and want to know how can I code it. I would be grateful if you help me)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Your code is calculating 1/sin1 + 1/sin2 + 1/sin3.   You should delete the line `i=i+1`.  It's not a bug, but the "for" loop is already increment i for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
import math
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
i = 1
s = 0
while i <= n:
    s += 1/math.sin(sum(range(1,i+1)))
    i += 1
    print(s)
```

---

If you want to see each item during iterations

```
import math
n = int(input("n = "))
i = 1
s = 0
while i <= n:
    r = 1/math.sin(sum(range(1,i+1)))
    s += r
    i += 1
    print(r)
```

Comment: the formula is 1(/sin(1))+1/(sin(1)+sin(2))+1/(sin(1)+sin(n)) needed to solve if the n=1,2,3,4 etc. Thank you for answering)

Comment: How to do it separately for each n?Because it shows all results for all n at once